# COUNT with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. Two tables named Sales.Customers and Sales.Orders.
2. Sales.Customers has a foreign key relationship to a column
   named CustomerID in Sales.Orders.

Requirement: A query that returns all the customers. The query must also return the number of orders that each customer placed.

Query 1:

```
    SELECT  cust.cutomername,
                NumberofOrders= COUNT(ord.OrderID)
    FROM Sales.Customers Cust
                LEFT JOIN
    Sales.Orders Ord
                ON Cust.CustomerID=Ord.OrderID
    GROUP BY
           Cust.CutomerName;
```

But I'm thinking of below one also,

Query2:

```
SELECT  cust.cutomername,
            NumberofOrders= COUNT(Cust.cutomerID)
FROM Sales.Customers Cust
            LEFT JOIN
Sales.Orders Ord
            ON Cust.CustomerID=Ord.OrderID
GROUP BY
       Cust.CutomerName;
```

From both which one do you recommend & why?

Comment: what's the difference of Query1 and 2?

Comment: NumberofOrders column

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT c.customername, COUNT(o.OrderID)
FROM Sales.Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Sales.Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CustomerName;
```

Probably returns all customers with meaningless counts -- probably `0` except for `OrderID`s that happen to match `CustomerID`s.

You probably intend:

```
SELECT c.customername, COUNT(o.OrderID)
FROM Sales.Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Sales.Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.CustomerName;
```

In this query, the `COUNT()` is counting the number of *matching* orders.  It can take the value of `0` for customers with no orders.

For this query:

```
SELECT c.customername, COUNT(c.OrderID)
FROM Sales.Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Sales.Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerName;
```

The `COUNT()` is returning the number of *rows*.  Every customer has at least one row, so the value would never be `0`.  Normally, you want the previous query.

Comment: For all customers no.of times they placed orders is my requirement .

Comment: @amarnadh . . . I think this answers your question.

Comment: Question is edited ago , So will you re check once ? and Please note that it has Foreign key relationship assigned .

Comment: there's no difference on query1 and 2

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ . . . The `JOIN` conditions look quite different to me.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ...Thats fine because it's my exam question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your solution:

```
select c.Customername,
    NumberOfOrders = (select count(o.OrderID) from Sales.Orders o where o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
from Sales.Customers c
order by c.Customername
```